# Jquery datepicker is initally opened not on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with JQuery, I have a problem. I used jQuery datepicker. When I first open the my site the datepicker open as well. However in my function I specificaly used  onSelect function but still see them initially.  How can I prevent this from happening? I tried using the below code. First, it shows the datepicker, then hides it but now can't open it on select.

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('show')  // to hide when open the site 
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide')
```

This is my original code. :

```
$( function() {
  var days = ['Pazar','Pazartesi', 'Salı', 'Çarşamba', 'Perşembe', 'Cuma', 'Cumartesi'];
   $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',
   language: 'tr',
    onSelect: function () {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate' ,true);
  var day = date.getDay();
  console.log(days[day]);
  console.log(day);
  $( "#day2" ).html( days[day] );
}

 });
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  var day = $('#datepicker2').datepicker('getDate').getDay();
  $( "#day2" ).html( days[day] );
  });
```

I have to datepicker btw one is called datepicker the other one is datepicker2

```
    <div class="input-wrapper">
          <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
          <input id="datepicker">
          <span id='day'></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: It would be better to improve the question by making a runnable example, as some things are missing such as the related html. Edit the question, click the `<>` icon on the tool bar to create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/7644018).

Comment: In your JS code, you're working with #datepicker2 but in your HTML code we got only "<input id="datepicker">". Please share your runnable code as @PaulT. said.